# Why is this SQL statement not retrieving DISTINCT records

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, Jobs and AdminUsersLog. The AdminUsersLog contains a log of actions performed on each job record in Jobs.

I am trying to retrieve a list of jobs which have been idle for longer than 7 days. This SQL below seems to be pulling out all log entries for each job and therefore pulling out older entries from the log which of course will always be older than 7 days.

I need to retrieve one record for each job where the AdminUsersLog.ulDate is older than 7 days.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Jobs.ID, Jobs.bStatus AS jStatus,  Jobs.sID, Jobs.insDate, Jobs.statusLabel, Jobs.cID, AdminUsersLog.ulDate, AdminUsersLog.ulJobType
FROM AdminUsersLog LEFT JOIN Jobs
ON (AdminUsersLog.ulJobID = Jobs.ID AND AdminUsersLog.ulJobType = 1) 
WHERE AdminUsersLog.ulJobType = 1 
AND (SELECT TOP(1) AdminUsersLog.ulDate FROM AdminUsersLog WHERE AdminUsersLog.ulJobID =     Jobs.ID AND AdminUsersLog.ulJobType = 1) < DATEADD(dd,-7,GETDATE()) 
AND Jobs.bStatus < 8
```

Top X results; http://pastebin.com/RcvxbxCV

Comment: Please Share Your Query Retrieve Table Record

Comment: Hi Hiral, Link to results above ;-)

Comment: ***WHAT*** database is this for? SQL is just the query **language** - not a product..... is this for **SQL Server**, or for Microsoft Access?

Comment: Sorry... MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You set your ulDate Column

AS

```
  SELECT CONVERT(DATE,ulDate) AS ulDate
```

ON Select Field

```
 SELECT CAST('2014-01-23 15:23:42.093' AS DATE) like this
```

beause your ulDate  field is not distinct

Query SET AS

```
    SELECT      DISTINCT Jobs.ID, Jobs.bStatus AS jStatus,  Jobs.sID, Jobs.insDate, Jobs.statusLabel, Jobs.cID, 
                CONVERT(DATE,AdminUsersLog.ulDate) AS ulDate, AdminUsersLog.ulJobType
    FROM        AdminUsersLog 
    LEFT JOIN   Jobs ON (AdminUsersLog.ulJobID = Jobs.ID AND AdminUsersLog.ulJobType = 1) 
    WHERE       AdminUsersLog.ulJobType = 1 
                AND (SELECT TOP(1) AdminUsersLog.ulDate FROM AdminUsersLog WHERE AdminUsersLog.ulJobID = Jobs.ID AND AdminUsersLog.ulJobType = 1) < DATEADD(dd,-7,GETDATE()) 
                AND Jobs.bStatus < 8
```

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for this although my results are still showing multiple records for each job... see results here; [link](http://pastebin.com/2F2FC2XS) You can see multiple Jobs.ID.. I just need the latest entry from the AdminUsersLog.

Answer (score 1):

Look at

```
SELECT TOP(1) AdminUsersLog.ulDate 
FROM AdminUsersLog 
WHERE AdminUsersLog.ulJobID = Jobs.ID AND AdminUsersLog.ulJobType = 1
```

This will get you an entry for the job. This can be any matching entry, because you specify no sort order for the TOP expression. Most often the randomly picked entry will be old. So either specify a sort order:

```
SELECT TOP(1) AdminUsersLog.ulDate 
FROM AdminUsersLog 
WHERE AdminUsersLog.ulJobID = Jobs.ID AND AdminUsersLog.ulJobType = 1
ORDER BY ulDate DESC
```

Or simply use MAX:

```
SELECT MAX(AdminUsersLog.ulDate)
FROM AdminUsersLog 
WHERE AdminUsersLog.ulJobID = Jobs.ID AND AdminUsersLog.ulJobType = 1
```